# How to bind a multiple word attribute in an AngularJS component

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can you pass in an attribute to an AngularJS component when the name is multiple words?

For example, suppose I have a test component defined like this

```
  .component('myComponent', {
    template: `<p> value = {{$ctrl.foo_bar}}`,
    bindings: {
      foo_bar: '<',
    }
  })
```

And I use it in the HTML like this

```
<my-component foo_bar="44444"></my-component>
```

For single word attributes, this works just fine. However, when I try to use a multi-word name like `foo_bar`, it doesn't work. Instead, it just shows up as blank (i.e. `value =`) in the html. I've tried everything I could think of, including underscores (`foo_bar`), dashes (`foo-bar`), and camel case (`fooBar`), but nothing works. I've tried searching online, but I couldn't find anything that helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You attribute in the HTML will use dashes like:

```
<my-component foo-bar="44444"></my-component>
```

And you component bindings should be camel cased:

```
.component('myComponent', {
    template: `<p> value = {{$ctrl.fooBar}}`,
    bindings: {
      fooBar: '=',
    }
  })
```

Comment: It looks like the trick I was missing is that the property on the controller itself must be camel cased as well.